# How do I submit form when changing date on kartik datepicker for Yii2

Tags: events, datepicker, yii2

When I change the date, I want to set an onChange event that submits the form. This will be a search filter that updates the results whenever I change the date on the datepicker. I can't figure out how to set the PluginEvent. I'm using Kartik datepicker for Yii2.

Thanks for your help always!

```
<?php echo $form->field($searchModel, 'available_from')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('frontend','Available from...')],
    'readonly' => true,
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'autoclose'=>true,
    'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy'
     ],
     'pluginEvents' => ['changeDate' => 'this.form.submit()'],
     ])->label(false);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `changeDate` event and detect the form to submit like below

```
echo $form->field($model, 'available_from')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Available from...')],
    'readonly' => true,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => ['changeDate' => "function(e){
       $(e.target).closest('form').submit();
    }" ]
])->label(false);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

```
'pluginEvents' => ["changeDate" => "function(e) {if (e.target.form) {e.target.form.submit();}}"],
```